# Show $u_n\rightharpoonup u$ in $W^{1,p}(a,b)\implies u_n\to u$ in $L^p(a,b)$

Tags: sobolev-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $p\in ]1,\infty [$. Show that $$u_n\rightharpoonup u\text{ in }W^{1,p}(a,b)\implies u_n\to u\text{ in }L^p(a,b).$$

I tried by contradiction, but it didn't really work...

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume that $-\infty<a<b<\infty$.

Remember that [a compact operator maps weakly convergent sequences into strongly convergent sequences](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/70410/70305):

> **Theorem 8.1-7 in [Kreyszig's book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=nZmpQgAACAAJ&dq=editions:o6E9qYL1N4YC&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi7iIbO5JbKAhUGkJAKHQ7fACwQ6AEIHDAA).** Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed spaces and $T: X \to Y$ a compact linear operator. If $x_n\rightharpoonup x $ in $X$ then $Tx_n\to Tx$ in $Y$.

Remember also that, according to the one dimensional version of [Rellich-Kondrachov Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1842147/70305), the embedding $\iota$ of $W^{1,p}(a,b)$ into $L^p(a,b)$ is compact for $p\in]1,\infty[$:

> **Theorem 8.8 in [Brezis book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=GAA2XqOIIGoC&printsec=frontcover&dq=brezis+book+sobolev+spaces&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLrLaM7ZHUAhUBTJAKHezBDT8Q6AEIIjAA#v=onepage&q=brezis%20book%20sobolev%20spaces&f=false).**
>   (a) The injection $W^{1,p}(a,b)\ni u\mapsto u\in C([a,b])$ is compact for $1 < p \leq \infty$;
>   (b) The injection $W^{1,1} (a,b)\ni u\mapsto u\in L^p (a,b)$ is compact for $1 \leq p < \infty$.

So, the desired result follows from the first theorem above by taking $X=W^{1,p}(a,b)$, $Y=L^p(a,b)$ and $T=\iota$.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Ascoli Arzela' theorem. If a sequence  converges weakly, it is bounded in $W^{1,p}$. Using the fundamental theorem of calculus and Holder's inequality you can prove that you have equi-continuity and equi-boundedness.